# How to find the master page a site is using?

Tags: master-page

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I have a root web site and some child sub-web site. I am using Blueband.master and related css files (e.g. Band.css).

My question is, for my parent site and child site, are they using the same master page files (including css files) or using different master page files (including css files) -- if they are using different ones, how to find which master page files (including css files) root site and child site are using? I ask this question is because I find some modifications of root web site does not apply to child site.

Answer (score 8):

My recommendation would be to go to the Site Settings as Marc indicated. From there under Look and Feel you will see the Master Page link.  Click on this and take a look at some of the selections.  For instance, if you want to inherit master from parent select the appropriate radio button.

Another way to confirm the master pages is by looking at the code in designer.  Open the default.aspx of page.  The top line of code should look like this
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"

YOu will also see the path to the master in the top right of the code window.

Answer (score 2):

1st ensure that these 2 features are enabled:
i. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure @/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site
ii. SharePoint Server Publishing @(ur_site)/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx

Then you can see **Master Page** under **Look & Feel** in Site Settings( @(ur_site)/_layouts/settings.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check is to use SharePoint Manager and on the spweb object look for the masterurl property.  Sometimes the masterpage can be customized at the site level instead of the site collection level.  Make sure your subsites are using your customized version of the masterpage and css that are located at the site collection root.

Comment: SharePoint Manager you mean what tool?

Comment: Yes, it's a tool you can download from codeplex

Comment: Do you mean when I select a sub-site, then from Properties Tab on the right side, check the MasterUrl property?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check which master page the site is using in Site Settings; no third party tool required.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!  I asked this same question (this one is actually a duplicate) and got a perfect answer in the form of a powershell script.  I did this and it worked like a charm!

The script exports a list of sites within a site-collection and tells which master pages are used where.

Really, this is the way to go.

[How to tell where a masterpage is used in a site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54052/how-to-tell-where-a-masterpage-is-used-in-a-site-collection)

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the master page a site is Use the object model and get the master page URL using web.MasterUrl.