# How to tell where a masterpage is used in a site collection?

Tags: master-page

Is there a way, within a `site collection`, to see all the pages that use a particular masterpage?

I have several masterpages and can't remember which ones are used where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use powershell to iterate through the site collection.  Something along the lines of this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://site.domain.com"
$webs = $site.AllWebs

$webs | % { 
    $obj = new-object System.Object
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name WebUrl -value $_.Url
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Master -value $_.MasterUrl
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CustomMaster -value $_.CustomMasterUrl
    $obj
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\folder\MasterPages.csv"
```

Comment: Hmmm... interesting answer. Let me try this out and I'll let you know how it works for me.