# which master page used in current sub site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, sharepoint-server, office-365-developer

I am using jquery on sub site of a site collection. i can see totally 4 master pages on sharepoint designer(seattle, Oslo, minimal, v4 ), here i added jquery to all the four but still the jquery not loaded on my browser. so that I like to find which master page is currently loaded, for that i revered the following link 
[How to tell where a masterpage is used in a site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54052/how-to-tell-where-a-masterpage-is-used-in-a-site-collection)... here it show the following error. [image]ultimately i don't know how to load jquery from master page.

Comment: Did you run `SharePoint Management Shell` or run the `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"` cmdlet?

Comment: i am using windows powershell

Comment: You must add the snap in mentioned in eirkb's comment to be able to use SP specific commands like Get-SPSite

Answer (score 1):

We Can use developer dashboard to know which master page that page is referring.
[Check this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2009/11/16/sharepoint-2010-enable-using-developer-dashboard.aspx)