# Cannot locate footer definition in master .html, yet it displays

Tags: master-page, designer, footer

We have an Intranet site based on seattle.master / .html. It has a footer displayed. When I look for the footer I cannot locate it in the .html or the .master.

1. how can I tell that our Intranet is really using seattle.master for its master page?
2. if it is using seattle.master as suspected, any idea how a footer could be getting displayed with no (obvious) code for it?

[image: bottom part of seattle.html]

Comment: Check the `masterurl` property of the `spweb` object using SharePoint Manager: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/941/how-to-find-the-master-page-a-site-is-using

Answer (score 0):

It turns out (another developer discovered) that the footer was being generated in JavaScript in a script file described in
/Pages/configure-page.aspx. I am still not sure how this is all wired together but the script file runs on document ready for every page which threw me off since I was looking only in the master page (where one would first expect to find a footer).

strVarF containt the footer HTML in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DeltaTopNavigation").before(strVar);
    $(".search-open").after(strVar2);
    $("#s4-bodyContainer").after(strVarF);
    $("#s4-bodyContainer").before(strVarBACKTOTOP);
    
    $("#siteIcon").appendTo("div[class='navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right']");
    $("#DeltaTopNavigation").appendTo("div[class='navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right']");
    $(".search-open").appendTo("div[class='navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right']");
});
```